# Upload a video to youtube with python?

Tags: python, youtube

is it possible to upload a video to youtube using python? Maybe an API or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries ([Old Answer URL](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python.html))

(First result from Googling "python youtube API". Please, try at least doing a single basic search before asking someone else to do it for you.)

Answer (score 2):

`youtube-upload` makes use of the Youtube Data API to upload videos on a Youtube channel by using commands in the console. I created this [video](https://youtu.be/IX8xlnk54Mg) to teach people how to make use of it.